# Creating polyline using mouse clicks with Python Addin tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

Can somebody tell me how to create a line geometry by mouse click with python addin?

I am using below code in python addin tool.

```py
class ToolClass8(object):
"""Implementation for Testmsg_addin.tool (Tool)"""
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.cursor = 3 
    self.shape = "Line" 


def onLine(self, line_geometry):
    NewL = "NewL"
    cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(NewL, ["SHAPE@"])
    array = arcpy.Array()
    part = line_geometry.getPart(0)
    for pt in part:
        array.add(pt) 

    cur.insertRow(arcpy.Polyline(array))
```

which throws the error:

**cur.insertRow(arcpy.Polyline(array))
TypeError: argument must be sequence of values**

Can somebody help me with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the help file for a [Tool Class](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/python-addins/tool-class.htm) the *onLine()* method returns a polyline object:

```
def onLine(self, line_geometry):
    cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("NewL", ["SHAPE@"])
    cur.insertRow([line_geometry])
```

Comment: Yes Its Working Now, thank you so much. but could not Understand what just happened by adding  parenthesis ?

Comment: @AkhilKumar It's expecting a list of strings (field names or tokens), and my answer provided only a string with a token, whereas this provides a list of one string.